Handle non-renewable in-app purchase in Multiple devices and multiple Accounts in same Device
We're using non-renewable subscriptions (monthly and yearly) in our app. We're encountering an issue where users who sign up for a subscription, log out, create a new account, and try to subscribe again are presented with a popup indicating that they already have an active subscription. This is because the transaction is tied to the Apple ID, which remains the same on the device. How can we address this so that new accounts on the same device can subscribe as if they were doing so for the first time?
I need to handle this issue, how can we handle this?

For a non-renewing subscription, the user can purchase it again by confirming that they want to purchase in response to the prompt

For an auto renewing sub you should associate the original purchase transaction id with the signed in user in your back end. Then, when a different user signs in but has that same original purchase id you can either move that entitlement from the old account to their new account or deny access to the purchased product.
